# Design a SVG using D3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I need create a SVG using D3Js as,

[image: Required Image]

I tried to create SVG image using D3JS

[image]

The above is generated using D3JS.

```
<svg width="236.6" height="158" viewBox="0, 0, 236.6, 158"><image href="/img/icon_threat_level_high.png" width="23.1" height="23.1" x="49.5" y="30.5" style="fill: rgb(255, 51, 51);"></image><image href="/img/icon_threat_level_high.png" width="23.1" height="23.1" x="49.5" y="65.5" style="fill: rgb(255, 51, 51);"></image><image href="/img/icon_threat_level_high.png" width="23.1" height="23.1" x="49.5" y="100.5" style="fill: rgb(255, 51, 51);"></image><g><text x="85.19999999999999" y="30.5" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 28px; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-stretch: normal; line-height: 1; letter-spacing: normal; fill: rgb(0, 103, 171); dominant-baseline: central;">10</text></g><g><text x="85.19999999999999" y="65.5" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 28px; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-stretch: normal; line-height: 1; letter-spacing: normal; fill: rgb(0, 103, 171); dominant-baseline: central;">08</text></g><g><text x="85.19999999999999" y="100.5" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 28px; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-stretch: normal; line-height: 1; letter-spacing: normal; fill: rgb(0, 103, 171); dominant-baseline: central;">03</text></g></svg>
```

Query :

- The first image tag has y "30.5", the same is set to the first text tag's y. But the Text tag is little above the icon.

This is my first work on SVG using D3JS.
Whats the best way to design that SVG using D3

My Idea is

```
<svg><g><image></image><text>10</text><text>GB</text><text>Name</text></g></svg>
```

Or

```
<svg><g><image></image><text><tspan>10</tspan><tspan>GB</tspan><tspan>Name</tspan></text></g></svg>
```

As "35", "GB", & "BitTorrent" has different font-size, color i prefer to choose tspan inside text & style those tspan's

Please suggest to design the SVG

Comment: The `y` attribute on a text element positions the "baseline", or the bottom of the text (excluding descents hanging below the line). So if you use a y-value that matches the center of the circle + its radius, then the bottom of the circle will align with the bottom of the text.

Comment: Yes, using `<tspan>` elements is a good idea so they can be styled differently. Each one can also have its own `dy` attribute to shift it up or down in relation to the rest of the text box.

Comment: thanks Steve, it works after adding radius 11.55 to text's y

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you add it using d3, like this?

```js
var  width = 236.6,
 height=158,
 margin = {top:20,left:30,right:20,bottom:20}

  var sign = '<path d="M244.709,389.496c18.736,0,34.332-14.355,35.91-33.026l24.359-290.927c1.418-16.873-4.303-33.553-15.756-46.011   C277.783,7.09,261.629,0,244.709,0s-33.074,7.09-44.514,19.532C188.74,31.99,183.022,48.67,184.44,65.543l24.359,290.927   C210.377,375.141,225.973,389.496,244.709,389.496z" data-original="#000000" class="active-path" data-old_color="#E9EAEF" fill="#EAEBF0"/><path d="M244.709,410.908c-21.684,0-39.256,17.571-39.256,39.256c0,21.683,17.572,39.254,39.256,39.254   s39.256-17.571,39.256-39.254C283.965,428.479,266.393,410.908,244.709,410.908z" data-original="#000000" class="active-path" data-old_color="#E9EAEF" fill="#EAEBF0"/>'


data = ["10","08","03"];

var svg =d3.select("body")
.append("svg")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right*6)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.style("background","lightgreen")
.append("g")
.attr("transform","translate(" +  margin.left + "," + margin.top*2 + ")");

var bigCircle = svg.append("g")
        .append("circle")
        .attr("r",margin.left/1.2)
        .attr("fill","red")
        .attr("cx", margin.right)
        .attr("cy", -7)

var bigText = svg.append("g")
        .append("text")
        .attr("fill","steelblue")
        .attr("font-size",50)
        .attr("x", margin.right*3.7)
        .attr("y", 10)
        .text("35")

var bigTextNext = svg.append("g")
        .append("text")
        .attr("fill","grey")
        .attr("font-size",25)
        .attr("x", margin.right*6.6)
        .attr("y", 8.5)
        .text("GB")

var bigTextNextNext = svg.append("g")
            .append("text")
            .attr("fill","steelblue")
            .attr("font-size",25)
            .attr("x", margin.right*9)
            .attr("y", 8.5)
            .text("BitTorrent");

var circles = svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform","translate(" +  0 + "," + margin.top*3 + ")")
      .selectAll("cirle")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("r", 12)
      .attr("cx", margin.right)
      .attr("cy", (d,i)=> i * margin.top*2)
      .attr("fill","red"); 

svg.append("g")
.attr("transform","translate(" +  0 + "," + margin.top*3 + ")")
.selectAll("text")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("text")
  .attr("font-size",22)
  .style("fill","steelblue")
  .attr("y", (d,i)=> (i+1) * (margin.top/2.8))
  .attr("x", margin.right*1.7)
  .attr("dx",12)
  .attr("dy",(d,i)=>  (margin.top*1.67) * i)
  .text((d)=> d)
```

```html
<!--jquery.min.js-->
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!--d3.min.js 4.13.0-->
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

If need clarification just let me know :)  the sign simbol can me also inserted this way

`var sign = '<path d="M244.709,389.496c18.736,0,34.332-14.355,35.91-33.026l24.359-290.927c1.418-16.873-4.303-33.553-15.756-46.011   C277.783,7.09,261.629,0,244.709,0s-33.074,7.09-44.514,19.532C188.74,31.99,183.022,48.67,184.44,65.543l24.359,290.927   C210.377,375.141,225.973,389.496,244.709,389.496z" data-original="#000000" class="active-path" data-old_color="#E9EAEF" fill="#EAEBF0"/><path d="M244.709,410.908c-21.684,0-39.256,17.571-39.256,39.256c0,21.683,17.572,39.254,39.256,39.254   s39.256-17.571,39.256-39.254C283.965,428.479,266.393,410.908,244.709,410.908z" data-original="#000000" class="active-path" data-old_color="#E9EAEF" fill="#EAEBF0"/>'`

then you create a group and add to it a .htmt(sign) but that svg code i found on internet is very big, you can scale it down or better edit it with a program to your desire size and theres no need to do scale transformation :) You can create ´g´ groups, bind it to data as with all elements before an translate  ´y´ as where the one who makes each one translate in y axis equally is the index.

Best regards.